# Modular Exponentiation doesn't work for large numbers in C

Tags: c

I don't know why it doesn't work well in large numbers since I've maximized the use of `unsigned long long`. Please help me. Or if this code is a total mess please do suggest a better and more efficient algorithm.  This is a homework and we are only allowed to use 
`#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`. I hope you could help me.

```
unsigned long long modularexp(unsigned long long a,unsigned long long b,unsigned long long mod)
{
    //a^b % mod
    unsigned long long product,pseq;
    product=1;
    pseq=a%mod;
    while(b>0)
    {
        if(b&1)
            product=(product*pseq)%mod;
        pseq=(pseq*pseq)%mod;
        b>>=1;
    }
    return product;
}
```

Comment: What `a` `b` and `mod` are you trying to use that causes the failure?

Comment: @JS1 a=1727 b= 62483 c=7491569251

Comment: Hi I'll probably get down voted for this,but I've written a library for fixed width decimal maths(digits and decimals configurable at compile time). Do you want a copy of this library

Comment: If your modulus is larger than 2^32 as in your case, you could get problems. The 64-bit integers are guanateed hold any product of two numbers less than 2^32; that guarantee doesn't necessarily hold if one of the numbers exceeds 2^32.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work well", do you mean results are not precise, or totally wrong ? Or do your program crashes ? Be more precise please.

Comment: @rhubarbdog sure if you don't mind.

Comment: @Aracthor the answers are wrong for huge numbers

Comment: @user333... It won't be while Monday or Tuesday

Comment: (If this is homework, you are probably expected to code it youtself and not use an external library. Jus' sayin'.) When a `%` operator is applied to `x * y` *after* the multiplication, you can bring down the size of `x * y` by first doing `x % mod` and `y % mod`. This will not change the result.

Comment: @User333... Sorry for the delay. Do you still need that Code? If so I'll need an email address to send it to.

Comment: @user3339866 please check comments. Do you want this listing. May be a problem as I have no ^ operator. I going to research how to do 3.6^4.1 from first principles if it ain't that bad I'll slot it in.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is good pre se, but it works reliably only if the modulus is less than 2^32. In your case, the modulus excees 2^32 and the following:

```
a * b < ulong.max
```

is not necessarily true, even if `a < mod` and `b < mod`.

You can fix this by adding an overflow check to all multiplications. If the multiplication `a * b` overflows, subdivide `a = a1 + a2` and calculate `a1 * b + a2 * b`.

The code below does this by introducing an additional function for modular multiplication.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long long ulong;

#define ULONG_MAX ((ulong) -1)

ulong modmul(ulong a, ulong b, ulong mod)
{
    if (a == 0) return 0;

    if (ULONG_MAX / a > b) {
        return (a * b) % mod;
    } else {
        ulong a1 = a / 2;
        ulong a2 = a - a1;

        return (modmul(a1, b, mod) + modmul(a2, b, mod)) % mod;
    }  
}

ulong modexp(ulong a, ulong b, ulong mod)
{
    ulong product = 1;

    a = a % mod;

    while (b > 0) {
        if (b & 1) {
            product = modmul(product, a, mod);
        }
        a = modmul(a, a, mod);
        b >>= 1;
    }

    return product;
}

int main()
{
    ulong a = modexp(1727, 62483, 7491569251LL);
    ulong expect = 5500747491LL;

    printf("%llu\n%llu\n", a, expect);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a test program that shows where the overflow occurs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static
unsigned long long modularexp(unsigned long long a,
                              unsigned long long b,
                              unsigned long long mod)
{
    unsigned long long product, pseq;
    product = 1;
    pseq = a % mod;
    while (b > 0) {
        if (b & 1) {
            if (pseq != 0 && product * pseq / pseq != product) {
                printf("multiplication overflow at b=%llu:"
                       " product=%llu, pseq=%llu\n",
                       b, product, pseq);
            }
            product = (product * pseq) % mod;
        }
        if (pseq != 0 && pseq * pseq / pseq != pseq) {
            printf("multiplication overflow at b=%llu:"
                   " pseq=%llu\n",
                   b, pseq);
        }
        pseq = (pseq * pseq) % mod;
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return product;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned long long a, b, mod, res;
    if (argc > 3) {
        a = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 0);
        b = strtoull(argv[2], NULL, 0);
        mod = strtoull(argv[3], NULL, 0);
        res = modularexp(a, b, mod);
        printf("%llu ** %llu %% %llu = %llu\n", a, b, mod, res);
    }
}
```

Running it with your values produces this:

```
~/dev/stackoverflow > ./t47 1727 62483 7491569251
multiplication overflow at b=3905: product=5150827583, pseq=5846688665
multiplication overflow at b=3905: pseq=5846688665
multiplication overflow at b=488: pseq=6744552923
multiplication overflow at b=244: pseq=4362729489
multiplication overflow at b=61: pseq=6056813204
multiplication overflow at b=30: pseq=6747710262
multiplication overflow at b=15: pseq=5762416609
multiplication overflow at b=7: pseq=5992947929
multiplication overflow at b=3: pseq=6028562833
multiplication overflow at b=1: product=7015761607, pseq=7047166445
multiplication overflow at b=1: pseq=7047166445
1727 ** 62483 % 7491569251 = 4674220559
```

You have to protect the computations with a function like that provided by `M Oehm`.